# How to compare a range of revisions using TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Is it possible to compare changes across multiple revisions using TortoiseGit or another tool?

I have used TortoiseSVN for many years now.  In the log window, I could select multiple revisions.  This would give me all of the files that changed across the revisions.  At a file level, I could see all of the differences in the file across all of the revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the two revisions you want to compare and then select "Compare revisions" on the revision list context menu.

Comment: In Tortoise SVN, you can select more than two revisions and it would show all the files modified on all the selected commits. I believe the question is asking if that is possible.